# svn complains that file does not exist

Tags: svn

```
$ svn mv file_util.c file_util.cpp                    
svn: E155010: Path '/.../file_util.c' does not exist
$ ls
-rwxrwxr-x  1 dargaud dargaud 10797 Oct  9 15:52 file_util.c*
...
```

The repository was fully up to date, so what is the problem ?!?

I managed to copy the file manually, svn rm the old one and svn add the new one, but I lost continuity doing that, which annoy me since it's a branch.

Answer (score 6):

The same thing just happened to me. In my case **the source directory had not yet been committed**, I could simply do a move.

Spent too much time on this, due to a very confusing error message. Hope this saves someone a couple of minutes.

Comment: I would like to add this note to your answer which I consider as the correct one and I upvoted it because it has lighten me up: The error message is **not** wrong from the point of view of the current `SVN` file structure. The file does **not** exist **yet** in the `SVN` database, so the error message is **correct**. But, of course, we human suppose it means the OS file system. Your answer _I could simply do a move_ is therefore correct because the internal `SVN` database structure has **NOT** to be modified.

Answer (score 3):

The same thing just happened to me.  In the end, it turned out that the directory I was trying to move had a **conflict**.  The error message ("does not exist") is very confusing (if not to say *plain wrong*), so it took me a while to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error message when trying to `svn mv` a file that is ignored (listed in the property `svn:ignore`).